# Great-great-great-great-... Example - Eloquent JS

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with the "Great-great-great-great-..." example from the Higher Order Functions chapter in Eloquent JS. I don't understand how one of the functions creates a value from an object only containing ancestry data. Here are the functions:

```
function reduceAncestors(person, f, defaultValue) {
   function valueFor(person) {
      if (person == null)
         return defaultValue;
      else
         return f(person, valueFor(byName[person.mother]),
                   valueFor(byName[person.father]));
    }
  return valueFor(person);
}
```

and

```
function sharedDNA(person, fromMother, fromFather) {
  if (person.name == "Pauwels van Haverbeke")
    return 1;
  else
    return (fromMother + fromFather) / 2;
}
```

I don't understand how valueFor(byName[person.mother]) generates a numerical value from an object like this:

```
"Carolus Haverbeke" : {
    "name": "Carolus Haverbeke", 
    "sex": "m", 
    "born": 1832, 
    "died": 1905, 
    "father": "Carel Haverbeke", 
    "mother": "Maria van Brussel"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look past the function declaration of `sharedDNA`, you'll see the following:

```
var ph = byName["Philibert Haverbeke"];
console.log(reduceAncestors(ph, sharedDNA, 0) / 4);
```

If you trace this up to `reduceAncestors`, the parameters map out to:

```
person -> { name: "Philibert Haverbeke", ... },
f -> sharedDNA,
defaultValue -> 0
```

Now, take a look at `valueFor()`. It always returns a number, either the `defaultValue`, or the result of `sharedDNA`, which always returns a number.  This is the key: if a person has no parent, then `defaultValue` is used, otherwise, it generates a ratio of sharedDNA between the given relationships, or the third case, '1', if the person happens to be named "Pauels van Haverbeke".

To answer your question, "How valueFor(...) generates a numerical value from a person object", is that it simply returns the value that `sharedDNA` generates recursively.

Answer (score 5):

After the declaration of `sharedDNA`, you'll see:

```
var ph = byName["Philibert Haverbeke"];
console.log(reduceAncestors(ph, sharedDNA, 0) / 4);
```

`byName` is an object full of key:value pairs like you've written for Carolus. The key is the person's name, and the corresponding value is the 'person object' that has key:value pairs for 'name', 'mother', 'father' etc. This is useful since for each recursive cycle, we will need to find out the result for the mother and father, and so we can easily look up the mother's and father's names for the current person, and then access their person objects from the byName object. So in line

```
var ph = byName["Philibert Haverbeke"];
```

we pull out this person object for Philibert and store it in a variable called `ph`. Then, `reduceAncestors` is called with this person object, the `sharedDNA` function, and a `defaultValue` of `0` (more on this in a moment). We are dividing by 4 because Philibert is the author's grandfather. So, this function will return the shared DNA between the grandfather and the great, great, great, great... grandfather. To then find the author's shared DNA, we would need to divide the result for his grandfather by 4 (each generation halves the shared DNA).

To more easily understand this example, I found it helpful to instead try to find the sharedDNA for some easier examples. First, let's try to find the shared DNA for Pauwels van Haverbeke, the great, great, great, great... grandfather we are using to compare in the first place. So we know the answer: Pauwels shares 100% of his own DNA.

So, in this case, `reduceAncestors` will be called with Pauwels' person object, the `sharedDNA` function, and a `defaultValue` of `0` with the following code:

```
var pauwels = byName["Pauwels van Haverbeke"];
console.log(reduceAncestors(ph, sharedDNA, 0));
```

In `reduceAncestors`, we will head into the else clause and the line

```
return f(person, valueFor(byName[person.mother]), valueFor(byName[person.father]));
```

will become

```
return sharedDNA(pauwels, valueFor(null), valueFor(null));
```

The `person.mother` and `person.father` expressions will evaluate to `null` since Pauwels' mother and father are not in the data set. `sharedDNA` wants to invoke, but needs to wait for the two `valueFor(null)` calls to evaluate.

When `valueFor` is called with `null`, it goes into the `if` clause since `person === null` will be true. Then, it will `return defaultValue`, which, as you recall, we had passed in as `0` in the original call to `reduceAncestors`.

So, now the line above becomes

```
return sharedDNA(pauwels, 0, 0)
```

If we look in the `sharedDNA` function, we see that we will evaluate the first `if` clause because `person.name == "Pauwels van Haverbeke"` will be true. Thus, we will return 1. In this way, and using the simplest example, you can see how `sharedDNA` returns a number.

Now, let's do one more example, this time with Pauwel's child, Lieven van Haverbeke. We will call it like so:

```
var pauwelsChild = byName["Lieven van Haverbeke"];
console.log(reduceAncestors(pauwelsChild, sharedDNA, 0));
```

Within `reduceAncestors`, we will head into the `else` clause and we will get to:

```
return sharedDNA(pauwelsChild, valueFor(byName["Lievijne Jans"]), valueFor(byName["Pauwels van Haverbeke"]));
```

We already know that `valueFor(byName["Pauwels van Haverbeke"])` returns 1. For the other argument, we have `valueFor(byName["Lievijne Jans"])`. This will eventually call `sharedDNA({Lievijne's: object}, valueFor(null), valueFor(null));` since neither of Lievijne's parents are in the dataset. This will evaluate to `sharedDNA({Lievijne's: object}, 0, 0);`.

Heading into `sharedDNA`, we see that it will `return (fromMother + fromFather) / 2;`, which in this case will be `return (0 + 0) / 2;`, or `0`. So, finally, we go back to

```
return sharedDNA(pauwelsChild, valueFor(byName["Lievijne Jans"]), valueFor(byName["Pauwels van Haverbeke"]));
```

and we now have

```
return sharedDNA(pauwelsChild, 0, 1);
```

We go into sharedDNA, and we will evaluate the statement `return (0 + 1) / 2;`, which will return `0.5`. This makes sense, since Pauwel's child will share 1/2 of his DNA.

Basically, `sharedDNA` waits for the calls to `valueFor` for mother and father to return. But remember, `valueFor` is calling `sharedDNA` since that’s the function we passed in. So, in essence, `sharedDNA` waits for itself to evaluate each parent, which in turn needs to evaluate each parent. This creates a tree of calls, until it hits null (a family member not in the data set) and returns `0`, or it hits Pauwels, and returns `1`. Then, the `0` or `1` is returned back, and the `sharedDNA` call from which it came will evaluate. As the outermost tree “branches” start returning `0` or `1`, they are combining together (and dividing by 2). Hence, a `1` from Pauwels keeps getting diluted by 1/2. Hence, you have smaller and smaller numbers.

I hope this helps! I wrote up a [more thorough explanation](http://kurtle.io/2015/09/04/recursion-in-javascript.html) which shows you how you can use the Chrome console to test out the code and add `console.log` statements to help you understand the flow of the recursion.